# How to update column value with existing column value in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

like:

```
update user.age = user.age+1 where id=123
```

try:

```
models.User.update({age:sequelize.col('age')+1},{where:{id:123}}).success()...
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

this way you can update with the existing value.

```
Sequelize.literal('no_of_sub_categorys + 1')
```

sample code :

```
CountModel.update({
    no_of_sub_categorys: Sequelize.literal('no_of_sub_categorys + 1')
 }, {
      where: {
      category_id: requestData.parent_id,
      active: 1
    }
 })
```

Comment: You can also use `sequelize.col()` and `sequelize.fn()` instead of `Sequelize.literal`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69045185/895245

Answer (score 4):

```
user.increment('age');
```

Notice that user should be an instance, not the model, so you should first do `models.User.find(123)`

http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/instance/#incrementfields-options-promise

Answer (score 2):

**`sequelize.col()` and `sequelize.fn()` minimal runnable example**

This is slightly cleaner than `Sequelize.literal` that was mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58903386/895245

```
const assert = require('assert');
const path = require('path');

const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Op } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'tmp.' + path.basename(__filename) + '.sqlite',
});

(async () => {
const Inverses = sequelize.define('Inverses',
  {
    value: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    inverse: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false }
);
await Inverses.sync({force: true})
await Inverses.create({value: 2, inverse: -2, name: 'two'});
await Inverses.create({value: 3, inverse: -3, name: 'three'});
await Inverses.create({value: 5, inverse: -5, name: 'five'});

// Initial state.
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).inverse, -2);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).inverse, -3);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).inverse, -5);
assert.strictEqual(await Inverses.count(), 3);

// Update to match another column.
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: sequelize.col('value'), },
  { where: { value: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).inverse, -2);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).inverse, 3);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).inverse, 5);
assert.strictEqual(await Inverses.count(), 3);

// Update to match another column with modification.
await Inverses.update(
  { inverse: sequelize.fn('1 + ', sequelize.col('value')), },
  { where: { value: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).inverse, -2);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).inverse, 4);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).inverse, 6);
assert.strictEqual(await Inverses.count(), 3);

// A string function test.
await Inverses.update(
  { name: sequelize.fn('upper', sequelize.col('name')), },
  { where: { value: { [Op.gt]: 2 } } },
);
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 2 } })).name, 'two');
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 3 } })).name, 'THREE');
assert.strictEqual((await Inverses.findOne({ where: { value: 5 } })).name, 'FIVE');
assert.strictEqual(await Inverses.count(), 3);

await sequelize.close();
})();
```

Generated SQLite update queries:

```
UPDATE `Inverses` SET `inverse`=`value` WHERE `value` > 2
UPDATE `Inverses` SET `inverse`=1 + (`value`)
UPDATE `Inverses` SET `name`=upper(`name`) WHERE `value` > 2
```

Tested on sequelize 6.5.1, sqlite3 5.0.2, node v14.17.0, Ubuntu 21.04.